# R / ggplot2: Add directlabels to ridgeline plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges, direct-labels, ridgeline-plot

I'm trying to add `directlabels` to lines of a ridgeline plot created by `ggridges`. It seems `directlabels` doesn't know what to apply the labels to. Is it possible to specify this? Or are the two packages incompatible?

```
# does not work
ggplot2::ggplot(iris,
                ggplot2::aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, height = Sepal.Width)) +
  ggridges::geom_density_ridges(stat = "identity") +
  directlabels::direct.label("first.points")

Error in UseMethod("direct.label") : 
  no applicable method for 'direct.label' applied to an object of class "character"
```

```
# does not work
ggplot2::ggplot(iris,
                ggplot2::aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, height = Sepal.Width)) +
  ggridges::geom_density_ridges(stat = "identity") +
  directlabels::direct.label.ggplot("first.points")

Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: I don't think direct.label is inheriting the aesthetics. So thinking the two packages are not compatible.

Comment: Have you considered annotate?

Comment: you cannot pass direct.label to a ggplot using "+". You need to store the object first,g = ggplot2::ggplot(iris,
    ggplot2::aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species, height = Sepal.Width)) +
    ggridges::geom_density_ridges(stat = "identity")

Comment: then directlabels::direct.label(g,"first.points")